# Should I add any file to my android or ios platforms so that all platforms will work as my web does?

Tags: firebase, ionic2

As I am a new in Ionic 2/Firebase and android/ios.

From Firebase Console I got the config variable and added it into my app.module.ts. Everything works fine on the web. What shall I add to my ionic 2 platforms so that my app would work on all platforms?

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? it's unclear what the intended behavior needs to be

Comment: What shall be added to let my ionic app works with firebase on android and ios as my app works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should add GoogleService-info.plist to the root of Ionic 2 Project and platforms/ios. And google-services.json to platforms/android.

I have written this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/58a1378480aca7386754130a/ionic-2-fcm-push-notification).